# background process constantly consuming high CPU

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

I was using a windows mobile 6.5 device, i want to use software to monitor my network, but from TaskManager, the monitor process is consuming 20% CPU times, is it any impact to my device except battery lift?

I am new to mobile development, if a program constantly consume high CPU, will it create a lot of heat and ruin the device ?

Comment: You want something more like serverfault.com.  Stackoverflow is for software development questions.

Comment: @Blank: I don't think mobile devices are on-topic for SF.  superuser definitely not.  There may be a mobile.se of some sort.  Actually this question might get good answers on http://android.stackexchange.com/ because the OS shouldn't make a difference.  The windows phone site would be really appropriate once it launches.  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone

Answer (score 0):

It is not very likely your device would take damage of high usage. You battery life time would be affected thou.

20% us much for a monitor thou, it should not take more than 5% in mean I would say.